# Multiple Rows as a Single Record in using group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join multiple columns in a single row but not getting the desired output.The query inside STUFF returns all data, but i want only that data which matches outer criteria. Any help would be appreciated

HERE IS A [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28926/2/0)

```
SELECT
COUNT (*) AS COUNT,
A.AlarmType,
A.DeviceNumber,
Latlong = STUFF (
    (
        SELECT
            ',' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, B.Latitude)
        FROM
            TableAlarmPacket B
        WHERE
            B.DeviceNumber = A.DeviceNumber AND B.AlarmType = A.AlarmType 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '')

FROM
TableAlarmPacket AS A
WHERE
A.DeviceNumber IN ('213WP2017006316')
AND A.AlarmType IN (4)
AND (
A.GPSDateTime BETWEEN '2018-09-01 14:00:00'
AND '2018-09-03 13:59:59'
)
GROUP BY

A.DeviceNumber,
A.AlarmType,
dateadd(
    MINUTE,
    datediff(MINUTE, 0, A.GPSDateTime) / 10 * 10,
    0
)
ORDER BY
MAX(A.Id) DESC
```

This is what i am getting.

```
6   4   213WP2017006316 -38.0348,-38.0353,-38.019,-37.9938,-37.9756,-37.9869,-38.0015
3   4   213WP2017006316 -38.0348,-38.0353,-38.019,-37.9938,-37.9756,-37.9869,-38.0015
2   4   213WP2017006316 -38.0348,-38.0353,-38.019,-37.9938,-37.9756,-37.9869,-38.0015
2   4   213WP2017006316 -38.0348,-38.0353,-38.019,-37.9938,-37.9756,-37.9869,-38.0015
2   4   213WP2017006316 -38.0348,-38.0353,-38.019,-37.9938,-37.9756,-37.9869,-38.0015
3   4   213WP2017006316 -38.0348,-38.0353,-38.019,-37.9938,-37.9756,-37.9869,-38.0015
```

expected output is

```
6   4   213WP2017006316 -37.6735,-37.6855,-37.6907,-37.6973,-37.7275,-37.7315
3   4   213WP2017006316 -37.6782,-37.6776,-37.6712
2   4   213WP2017006316 -37.7074,-37.7068
2   4   213WP2017006316 -37.76,-37.7356
2   4   213WP2017006316 -37.8276,-37.8279
3   4   213WP2017006316 -37.9271,-37.893,-37.8856
```

First field is of count. My count and Latlong field is not reflecting same data.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Added Sample and expected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the condition of `GPSDateTime` in the `STUFF` query like the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (*) AS COUNT,
    A.AlarmType,
    A.DeviceNumber,
    Latlong = STUFF (
        (
            SELECT
                ',' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, B.Latitude)
            FROM
                TableAlarmPacket B
            WHERE
                B.DeviceNumber = A.DeviceNumber AND B.AlarmType = A.AlarmType 
    and dateadd(
        MINUTE,
        datediff(MINUTE, 0, A.GPSDateTime) / 10 * 10,
        0
    ) = dateadd(
        MINUTE,
        datediff(MINUTE, 0, B.GPSDateTime) / 10 * 10,
        0
    )

            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '')

FROM
    TableAlarmPacket AS A
WHERE
    A.DeviceNumber IN ('213WP2017006316')
AND A.AlarmType IN (4)
AND (
    A.GPSDateTime BETWEEN '2018-09-01 14:00:00'
    AND '2018-09-03 13:59:59'
)
GROUP BY

    A.DeviceNumber,
    A.AlarmType,
    dateadd(
        MINUTE,
        datediff(MINUTE, 0, A.GPSDateTime) / 10 * 10,
        0
    )
ORDER BY
    MAX(A.Id) DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28926/5/0)